Blazor .NET 8 - How to know where to perform dependency injection (Server side and client side)
I have a problem with the standard Blazor template that I've expanded the content with more pages.
From the standard template, I want to call an external API (with my own base address). This page contains a list of customer table. This table will display "Loading.." upon page load, once the data is fetched from the API server, the table is then populated with data.
To my understanding, with this basic interaction, I need to implement this page on the Client side project (Webassembly). So I created a page with code-behind that fetch the data using typed HttpClient of CustomerServiceApiClient.
public class CustomerServiceApiClient(HttpClient client)
{
    public async Task<PaginatedResponse<CustomerDto>> GetPaginatedCustomersAsync()
    {
        var result = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<PaginatedResponse<CustomerDto>>("customers");
        return result ?? new PaginatedResponse<CustomerDto> { Data = [] };
    }
}

The page that calls the client to fetch the data is implemented as.
public partial class CustomerSummaryPage : ComponentBase
{
    public PaginatedResponse<CustomerDto> PaginatedCustomers { get; set; } = new();

    [Inject]
    private CustomerServiceApiClient? CustomerServiceApiClient { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetCustomersAsync();
    }

    public async Task GetCustomersAsync()
    {
        PaginatedCustomers = await CustomerServiceApiClient.GetPaginatedCustomersAsync();
    }
}

The in Program.cs of the client project, the dependency injection and the HttpClient definition are added here.
// Dependency Injection of the typed HttpClients
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomerServiceApiClient>();

// Add typed HttpClient for all internal API calls
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<CustomerServiceApiClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["WebApi:CustomerServiceApi"]))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthorizedHttpClientHandler>();

However I get this error, saying the service was not registered.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'CustomerServiceApiClient' on type 'Maliev.Intranet.Client.Pages.Customers.CustomerSummaryPage'. There is no registered service of type 'Maliev.Intranet.Client.Services.CustomerServiceApiClient'.
If I copy the dependency injection over to the server side project. The error is gone and the app starts but the base address is always null, but both of my appsettings.json in server project and client project are filled with values.
{
  "WebApi": {
    "BaseAddress": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx",
    "CustomerServiceApi": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx",
    "CurrenciesServiceApi": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}

How is it suppose to be done? The page and the typed HttpClient are implemented in the Client project. The page that wants to make an API call resides in the client project.

Inject by interface the implementation can be different the api service on the client should only talk directly to your servers controllers. The server's implementation should talk to the third parties api's. Secure and no secrets bleed. Then you truly have the benefits of InteractiveAuto

Which Template did you use?  Interactivity type and location?

@BrianParker Last time I did this I got error with JSInterop cannot modify the header to attach the access token. Maybe that was when I use the template and remove most of the unknown implementations that came with the Blazor template (PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider, etc.) as I want only to implement stuff that I find necessary. But that break things.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I use the Blazor WebApp template. with Auto (server+webassembly) interactivity and per page/component interactivity.

@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly doesn't disable prerender. 
The page is actually prerendered using SSR(server static render) first. Then after a while when the WASM resources are downloaded, the page will turn to be rendered using pure WASM (client-side).
Becasue it involves SSR, you will also need to register the services on server project. If you want to disable prerender just use 
@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender:false))
For the question "base address is always null", I have tested the codes but both client and server httpclient get the base address correctly. One thing to mention that is during prerender SSR("Server static render"), the page lost interactive, all buttons won't work. So I saw the page may have a button to call GetCustomersAsync, which probably never get triggered in SSR. It will only work during pure WASM render.
